# Angular Animation select element outside using query

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

Is it possible to select an `Element` outside the Angular Animation Declaration using query? i have this code. Let say I do have two components.

layout.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

app-header.component.html

```
<header  [@MobileNavAnimation]="isMenuNavOpened ? 'navOpened' : 'navClosed'">
    <input id="sideMenuInput" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isMenuNavOpened"/>
</header>
```

This will be rendered like this structure

```
<layout>
   <app-header></app-header>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</layout>
```

Animation.ts

```
trigger('MobileNavAnimation', [
    transition('navClosed <=> navOpened', [
        query('layout', [
            state('navOpened', style({ position: 'absolute', left: '-100px', 'padding-right': '100px' }))
        ])
    ])
]);
```

So as you can see, I declare my animation to `app-header` component, but my animation is trying to change the higher element. Is this possible?

PS: I can achieve this through `Input` and `Output` of `@angular/core`, but I am trying to do experiment the capabilities of Angular Animation.